# Accessing razor Id @Html.IdFor in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Using `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyField)` results in `<input id="MyField" name="MyField" type="text" value="" />` and if I want to access that element in jquery I do so as follows `$("#MyField")`. What can be done for `id="@Html.IdFor(m => Model.AmountOptionList)` ? How can I use the Id of that element in my jQuery function?

Following is my code:

```
<div id="originalAmount_@differAmountId" class="divoriginalAmount">

      <select class="cs-select cs-skin-border billAccountAmount " data-label="@StringResource.Lbl_Pay " id="@Html.IdFor(m => Model.AmountOptionList)">
```

I want to focus on this select box when page is loaded so I need to do following

```
$('#@Html.IdFor(m => Model.AmountOptionList)').focus();
```

but it is not working nor  `$('#AmountOptionList').focus();` Unfortunately I can not use css class here.

Comment: What html element does the second thing generate?  You seem to have a grasp on how to make it work with the first one.

Comment: @Taplar I updated my question

Comment: Is that the actual mark that is generated on the page?  Or is that the source prior to it being generated?

Comment: @Taplar That is the actual Mark

Comment: Then something about this smells off, and I'll have to wait for someone knowledgable in razor to chime in.  Because my assumption would be that that script in the id="" should be compiled somehow into an actual value, and it doesn't look like it is.

Comment: @Taplar when I inspect an element I see an id but when I use that Id as `$('#id').focus(); ` It doesn't work too!  (though works with `$('.class').focus()` strangely)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180070/discussion-between-prasanna-and-taplar).

Comment: The code you have shown works fine (as I noted in your previous question). I can only assume your script is in an external js file (razor code is not parsed on external files)

Comment: @StephenMuecke now I am using the value of the Id in jQuery, not the razor code and I got that Id after inspecting an element. while loading the page It should map that Id to the one I am specifying and apply `.focus()` which is not happening

Comment: My comment was about using `$('#@Html.IdFor(...)` in an external js file :)